# Navigate to mainpage after clicking app in share option list?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to navigate back to my mainpage after clicking my app in share option list.

This is my main page: https://gyazo.com/831db63433d9b3e2051ed605dc3489af

When i click my app in the share option list here: https://gyazo.com/47234162530078e1a83cdfb17eaf5401

I come to this page: https://gyazo.com/11cfb0f6818127e2cd4ef51d5ed970b9

But i want to navigate to picture 1 when i click my app in the share option list. How can i do this? The share intent activity is in the AndroidManifest.xml as you see on the picture. The page that is shown in picture one is called "TabbedPagePage" and that is the page i am trying to get to in the first place, without getting to this ugly, no content dark picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you need to set the `IntentFilter` for your `MainActivity` instead of use another activity. 
And it will navigate to main page eventually.
For example:

```
    [Activity(Label = "Navigatetomainpage", Icon = "@drawable/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
    [IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionSend }, Categories = new[] { Intent.CategoryDefault }, DataMimeType = "image/*", Label = "Navigatetomainpage")]
    [IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionSend }, Categories = new[] { Intent.CategoryDefault }, DataMimeType = "text/plain", Label = "Navigatetomainpage")]
    [IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionSendMultiple }, Categories = new[] { Intent.CategoryDefault }, DataMimeType = "image/*", Label = "Navigatetomainpage")]    
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {   
            Intent intent = Intent;
            String action = Intent.Action;
            String type = intent.Type;

            if (Intent.ActionSend.Equals(action) && type != null)
            {
                if ("text/plain".Equals(type))
                {
                    // Handle text being sent
                    // ...
                    // ...
                    // ...
                }
                else if (type.StartsWith("image/"))
                {
                    // Handle single image being sent
                    // ...
                    // ...
                    // ...    
                }
            }
            else if (Intent.ActionSendMultiple.Equals(action) && type != null)
            {
                if (type.StartsWith("image/"))
                {
                    // Handle multiple images being sent
                    // ...
                    // ...
                    // ...                        
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // Handle other intents, such as being started from the home screen                    
            }    

            TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
            ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
            LoadApplication(new App());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hey! i added "NavigationPage pag = new NavigationPage(new TabbedPagePage());" in all the events, but it doesnt redirect me

Comment: @Rodnik `NavigationPage pag = new NavigationPage(new TabbedPagePage());` is used in xamarin.forms project. Are you using xamarin.forms or xamarin.android?

Comment: I am using Xamarin.Forms. However , i only selected ios and android when building project. But yes, it is a xamarin.forms

Comment: https://gyazo.com/ee692bb5c01a463d4a3a5b0e84dbbe38 this is how it currently looks

Comment: @Rodnik I have modified my answer, please check it.

Comment: Yes it works now! Had to change the namespace to .droid after aswell because it had problem with the resource.layout! Thank you Billy, highly appriciated!